# Is a person without a male child not eligible for Moksha?

Tags: moksha

Aputhrasya gathir nasthi? Does it really mean a family without a male child is not eligible for moksha? What about families with only girl childs?

Comment: @keshav-srinivasan I am not asking here about to have a children. I know there is a story itself in mahabharatha (Jaratkara for his ancestors to move to heaven) that atleast there should be a child. But what about a male vs female? Male enables a household to attain moksha. What about female child?

Comment: The said verse is from a purana, i.e. smriti. Smritis have limited contextual application. That being said the 3 words you have quoted is a part of larger couplet. Read it here and you will understand what the author is trying to say. http://stotrarathna.blogspot.in/2012_04_01_archive.html

Comment: Everyone is eligible for Moksha, what matters most is Will for realization (if you're a jnani), faith in Bhagavan (if you're a bhakta) and detachment from fruits of actions (if you're karma yogi). All the best